# React -looping through an array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops

i fetched an api from coinlayer and the data it returns is an object. I tried using state to create an empty array then setState to set the data there but when i try to loop through it using map the error generated says "map is not a function"

a screenshot of the data from the api

[image]

here's the code

```js
class App extends Component{

  state={names:[] }

 



  componentDidMount(){
    fetch('http://api.coinlayer.com/live?access_key=c8c0ef65a659c37726364c68e6fdb887&expand=1')
    .then((response)=>response.json())
    .then((data)=>{
      console.log(data.rates);
      this.setState({names:data.rates})
      
   
    })
  
  }
  
  
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="Body">
        <div className="Navbar"><h1 style={{textAlign:'center'}}>Crypto Dashboard</h1></div>
       

        

        <DashBoard names={this.state.names}  />
       

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

export default App;

Comment: The data is an object, not an array. You can't use `.map` on objects, only arrays. If you want to loop through the object you can use something like `Object.keys(this.state.names).map(key => {...})`

Comment: You need to use something like `Object.keys` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to work with an object, not an array.

You can use `Object.keys` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

e.g.

```
    fetch('http://api.coinlayer.com/live?access_key=c8c0ef65a659c37726364c68e6fdb887&expand=1')
    .then((response)=>response.json())
    .then((data)=>{
      let names = [
      Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
        names.push(data[key]) // Push the values to the array
        names.push(key]) // Or push the key to the array (whatever you need)
      })
      this.setState({ names })
    })
```

There's many other ways to do the same.

Comment: Thanks, it worked.However how do  i give my lists the unique key when the object from the api does not have id number property?

Comment: @Akanimo that's another question, to which you can find the answer on this forum. If I answered your question please mark it as accepted.